# Display the color histogram for an image

Tags: php, image, histogram

I'm searching for a function in PHP which extract the [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) from an image to an PNG file. This PNG file will be located in a different folder than the actual image and the function must handle large images (over 3 MB). I did find a [function almost similar to my request](http://bubble.ro/How_to_create_the_histogram_of_an_image_using_PHP.html) but the function can not handle large images and it didn't showed the histogram nor the image as showed on their website (it showed only a blank window with a border).

I hope that you guys can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using this one for our projects:
http://www.histogramgenerator.com/

We did not experience issues with large images. It's not free, but we definetly feel it's 
worth the money we paid for. The class also offers many additional interesting features.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) 29.99€ or $29.99 (they have added both currencies and non of them was linked which was very confusing) was not the cheapest for this sort of function but I believe you :) I'll take a look at it when I can.

Answer (score 0):

It is a script to draw a simple histogram like *Photoshop* does (only similar, because I suspect it scale both axes with a *sigmoid* function, or something like that).

I wrote a `scale()` function where you can use a last bool argument to do a linear histogram, or use a square root scale to boost low values.

```
<?php
    //Just in case GD needs more memory
    ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

    $filename='image1.png';
    //Attempt to open 
    [$width, $height, $type]=getimagesize($filename);
    if($type==IMAGETYPE_PNG){
        $img=imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    }

    //Histogram initialization
    $hist = array(
      'red'=>array_fill(0,256,0),
      'green'=>array_fill(0,256,0),
      'blue'=>array_fill(0,256,0)
    );

    //Counting colors
    for($x=0;$x<$width;++$x){
        for($y=0;$y<$height;++$y){          
            $bytes=imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
            $colors=imagecolorsforindex($img,$bytes);
            ++$hist['red'][$colors['red']];
            ++$hist['green'][$colors['green']];
            ++$hist['blue'][$colors['blue']];
        }
    }

    //Drawing histogram as a 256x128px image            
    $width=256;
    $height=128;
    $newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);    
    //Max frequency for normalization
    $maxr=max($hist['red']);
    $maxg=max($hist['green']);                
    $maxb=max($hist['blue']);             
    $max=max($maxr,$maxg,$maxb);

    function scale($value,$max,$height,$scale=FALSE){
        $result=$value/$max; //normalization: value between 0 and 1
        $result=$scale?$result**0.5:$result; //sqrt scale       
        $result=$height-round($result*$height); //scaling to image height
        return $result;
    }

    $top=220; //255 seems too bright to me
    for($x=0;$x<$width;++$x){
        for($y=0;$y<$height;++$y){          
            $r=($y>scale($hist['red'][$x],$maxr,$height,TRUE))?$top:0;
            $g=($y>scale($hist['green'][$x],$maxg,$height,TRUE))?$top:0;
            $b=($y>scale($hist['blue'][$x],$maxb,$height,TRUE))?$top:0;
            $colors=imagecolorallocate($newimg,$r,$g,$b);
            imagesetpixel($newimg,$x,$y,$colors);
        }
    }

    //Saving the histogram as you need
    imagepng($newimg,'.subfolder/histogram.png');

    //Use the next lines, and remove the previous one, to show the histogram image instead
    //header('Content-Type: image/png');
    //imagepng($newimg);
    exit();
?>
```

Note I'm not checking if *filename* exist, neither if `getimagesize()` or `imagecreatefrompng()` failed.

Answer (score -1):

I tested this with a 2MB (5800 x 5800) PNG Image. Basicaly the "imagecreatefrompng()" method is consuming lot of memory.

So before making the call, I increased the memory al the way up to 512M and set the execution time to 5 mins

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(5*60);
```

After the Image is created, restore the memory limit

```
$im = ImageCreateFromPng($source_file); 
ini_restore('memory_limit');
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#73546

Comment: Thanks but I can't upload more than 64M in memory_limit on my webhost :/ And this didn't help me to create the histogram of an image.